# Rotate using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to rotate a div. After a lot of research, there is no javascript to rotate a div without using the css transform, unless jquery library is used. The problem is I want to do a small rotation, and adding the library for that is not an option for me.Css transform does not work on IE.

With [this example clock](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) the minutes, hours and seconds rotate using javascript itself.

Can anyone help me get a div to rotate on IE7, and above using javascript itself without any additional libraries?

Comment: Nothing rotates on that clock, and it doesn't use just JavaScript. There is a separate div for every dot, and JS accesses the DOM to move each div that makes up the hand that is being moved.

Comment: Mmmmm http://css3pie.com/ tastes goooooood. (Hint: CSS3 on IE)

Comment: @Fred I dare you to rotate something in ie8 and lower by using css3pie. http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/

Comment: @Lollero: A ha, I did not realise. :D

Comment: You may find http://w3fools.com/ useful...

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit late, but I have written some code to do this.

http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/73DzT/

```
Object.prototype.rotate = function(d) {
    var s = "rotate(" + d + "deg)";
    if (this.style) { // regular DOM Object
        this.style.MozTransform = s
        this.style.WebkitTransform = s;
        this.style.OTransform = s;
        this.style.transform = s;
    } else if (this.css) { // JQuery Object
        this.css("-moz-transform", s);
        this.css("-webkit-transform", s);
        this.css("-o-transform", s);
        this.css("transform", s);
    }
    this.setAttribute("rotation", d);
}
```

can be used with regular objects or with JQuery objects. and stores an attribute called "rotation" to give you it's current rotation value. You can play around with this and see what you can come up with.

Comment: Now you just need to add IE filter support 3:D

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do using raw CSS without javascript and jQuery:

```
$('#idElement').css({
    /*modern browsers*/
     '-moz-transform':'rotate(88deg)',
     '-webkit-transform':'rotate(88deg)',
     '-o-transform':'rotate(88deg)',
     '-ms-transform':'rotate(88deg)'
     /*IE:*/
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476), /* IE6,IE7 */
     -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(SizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476)"; /* IE8 */
});
```

You can most definately change element attributes using simple javascript such as:

```
document.getElementById("idElement").setAttribute("-moz-transform", "rotate(88deg)");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it why not using jQuery when its lots easier solution?

Here is fast script i written

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#element').easyRotate({
       degrees: 45
    });
});
```

For javascript you need to make pictures of your div and than rotate those pictures inside the div. I made simple example of doing that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="div1">
        <img name="img1" src="myimage1.jpg" id="img1">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="Rotate this image" onclick="rotate()">
    </div><script type="text/javascript">
var tally = 0;
    function rotate() {
    if (tally == 0) {
    document.images["img1"].src= "myimage2.jpg";
    tally = 1;
    return true;
    }
    else {
    document.images["img1"].src= "myimage1.jpg";
    tally = 0;
    return true;
    }
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dzoki, the target of website, majority of users are having GPRS, which offers very slow connectivity. My site on a whole is 50kb, on the client side and I do not want to use jQuery since the (minified, even)library is 35 kb. since just one rotation is required, adding jquery doesn't seem good.

Comment: The javascript above flips images inside a div instead of rotating it. As far as i can think, i'll have to use Math library to change absolute positions of the div i have to rotate

Comment: you can use online library can't you? I'm not familiar with it. I will try to find another solution for it then, if you don't get better answer at that time.